# Java Optional: flatmap and orElseGet

Tags: java, java-stream

I've coded that:

```
Optional.ofNullable(this.cache.get(id))
    .orElseGet(this.referenceService.get(id));
```

The problem is that `this.referenceService.get` returns an `Optional`.

So, I'm getting this compilation message:

> The method `orElseGet(Supplier<? extends Reference>)` in the type `Optional<Reference>` is not applicable for the arguments (`Optional<Reference>`)

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you have to call `.orElseGet(() -> this.referenceService.get(id))`.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with java 9 you can use [Optional.or()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#or-java.util.function.Supplier-)

```
Optional<String> foo = Optional.empty();
Optional<String> bar = Optional.ofNullable("Bar");
System.out.println(foo.or(() -> bar));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java 9, you have access to `Optional.or`, which accepts a `Supplier<Optional<T>>`.

If not, the below pattern works:

```
Optional.ofNullable(this.cache.get(id))
    .orElseGet(() -> this.referenceService.get(id)
        .orElseThrow(()-> new RuntimeException("Expected service to return something")));
```